# How to prove that a solution to a homogenous wave equation IVP (Cauchy) on $R$ is in $C^2(t\geq 0)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

So, my problem is the following:

I have a classical IVP (Cauchy problem) for a wave equation on the real line:

$u_{tt} = a^2u_{xx} + f(t,x)$

$u|_{t=0} = u_0(x)$

$u_t|_{t=0} = u_1(x)$

By definition, the IVP is searching for $u\in(C^2(t>0)\cap C^1(t\geqslant0))$.

I want to prove a stronger thing:

I want to prove that if $f(x,y) \equiv 0$ and the solution to the IVP exists (but is not necessarily unique), then:

$u \in C^2(t\geqslant0)$

$u_0 \in C^2(R)$

$u_1 \in C^1(R)$

My initial desire was to try and use the D'Alembert formula and try to differentiate the solution at $t=0$.
But the very usage of D'Alembert formula requires at least some constraints on $u_0$ and $u_1$.

I don't even have a clue how to approach such problems. Most of the theorems in the PDE course deal with sufficient conditions, whereas here I need a necessary condition.

I could say something like:

Suppose this is not true, and $lim_{t\to0} u(t,x) =g(x) \neq u_0(x)$

We could differentiate them (since $u\in C^1(t=0)$):

$g_x(x) =? u_{0x}(x)$

Does it tell us anything?
Well, we could do something like $g_{xx} = u_{0xx}$, but alas, we are not sure that we can differentiate the second time.

So, I am confused, any suggestions appreciated.